# SharePoint Online - Workflow email not received by one user

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, permissions

We have a News Blog sub site that users post stories to. They have some Email options when posting items, one of which is 'Email all Staff'. If they select 'Yes', everyone gets an email to let them know a new story has been posted.

I have 1 user (User A) who has Contribute permissions to the News Blog.

If they post to the News Blog the Workflow fails to send the email with an error -

'Access Denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource'

Also, if another user (User B) posts to the New Blog the Workflow will email all staff except User A.

All the lists in the site inherit permissions from the Blog so User A and User B have the same permissions throughout the site.

Feel like I'm missing something but can't for the life of me see what.

All help greatly appreciated.

Dan

Comment: check this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b97d6f44-bbbb-4fce-88bb-e5fb06f06778/sharepoint-online-workflow-error?forum=appsforsharepoint

Comment: Hi Waqas, I've followed your link and Limited Lockdown is enabled on the Site Collection but only 1 user seems to be having an issue. If this was the cause wouldn't all users be affected ?
Also, I've checked the group and everyone can see the members of the SharePoint Groups. 
I don't currently have access to SPDesigner to see which groups are being emailed but I'll ask if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its likely the user is not on your domain, or doesn't have rights in your AD/Azure environment where SP has rights. Is this public facing or an internal site?

Comment: Hi John, this is an Internal Site. I'll check what domain the user logs on to. Thanks

Comment: John , I've got confirmation that User A (whose Email workflows fail) is on the same Domain as User B who can use the Email Workflow fine.

Comment: What rights in AD/Azure should I be looking at ? Comparing the 2 users ID's doesn't reveal anything obviously different.

Comment: Think I've found the answer to at least part of this issue. User A was not in the distribution list that the workflow uses when emailing all staff. So this explain why they received no emails when User B posts.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, you'd have to revisit the workflow to see it.